# Database design for communication records and communication preferences

Tags: database, database-design

I need to design a DB structure that will keep records of Customer Communication information and preferred communication type for certain situations. Basic design will include

- *Communication Records*: Each customer may have one or more phone number, address, e-mail address etc. recorded in the database. Or they may not have any defined record for some of these cases (like he may have a phone number but not have any address defined in the system)
- *Record sub-types*: A phone number can be a line or a GSM phone number. Address can be home or work address etc.
- *Customer Preferences*: Customers will set their preferred type of communication for some situations. Situations will include:

  - Sending single-usage password for login (just mobile phones)
  - Sending billing information ( may be mobile phone number, e-mail address or normal address.)

So, some preferences will accept a certain communication type (Only phone number), or sub-type (only GSM phone number) while some may accept more than one type (address or e-mail)

I am trying to make the DB design to handle this and it must be an optimized  structure.

I am having hard time about deciding the structure. Creating a single table for all communication records that have a *type* (phone) and a *sub-type* (GSM) will have many unnecesarry fields for each record (since an address will contain DB fields like city and country, while a phone record will not, while it needs number field) Creating seperate tables for each is better, but this time I will have problems in defining *preferences* table because some preferences will only accept a sub-type (like GSM phone) while some will accept more than one type (like address or e-mail)

What will be the best database design approach for a such need? DBMS has not been decided yet but it might be Postgresql or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Address needs to be in a separate table, because as you said, there are many columns to an address.  You can put a flag in the Address table to differentiate between a work address and a home address, if necessary.

```
Address
-------
Address ID
Street
City
...
```

The Address ID is an auto incrementing integer or long.  It's the primary (clustering) key.

The remainder of the communication records can go in a Contact table.  The table would look like this:

```
Contact
-------
Contact ID
Contact Type (Land line phone, email, cell phone, etc.)
Contact Information
```

The Contact ID is an auto incrementing integer or long.  It's the primary (clustering) key.

The Contact Information is a varchar that holds the email address or the telephone number.

The Preference table would look like this:

```
Preference
----------
Preference ID
Preference Order
Customer ID
Preference Type (address or contact)
Address ID
Contact ID
```

The Preference ID is an auto incrementing integer or long.  It's the primary (clustering) key.

The Preference Order defines the order of the preferences.  Email first, then phone, as an example.

The Customer ID is a foreign key back to the Customer table.

Either the Address ID or the Contact ID would be a foreign key back to the Address table or the Contact table, respectively.

Comment: Shouldn't `Customer ID` must be column in both `Contact` and `Address` tables, otherwise how could I distinct the owner of the Contact or Address record? For data consistency, moving `Record ID` form `Preferences` to `Address` and `Contact` seems better

Answer (score 0):

Pick up a good data model pattern book, such as by Hay, Silverston or Fowler's "Analysis Patterns".

You want to abstract Email, Phone, Mailing Address, and Web Address into an abstract Address type, so that you can point a single foreign key to any kind of address. Use Table Inheritance.

GSM Number is not a subtype of Phone Number, because you should only use inheritance for things that never change, and someone's phone number can be moved from a cell to landline.

```
create table address (
  id serial primary key,
  type smallint not null references address_type(id) -- elided
);

create table address_phone_number (
  id int primary key references address(id),
  phone_number text
);

/*
add subtype tables for email, web, mailing...
*/

create table party (
  id serial primary key,
  type int not null references party_type(id), -- elided
  name text not null
);

create table party_address (
  party_id int not null references party(id),
  address_id int not null references address(id),
  role char(2) not null, -- examples: wf=work fax, ho = home
  primary key party_id, address_id, role)
);
```

you could subtype part_address to say party_address_phone_number to add a telephone extension